# How to disable autoformat, when writing to Excel-Cell from C#

Tags: c#, excel-interop

I have written an application which writes content into an Excelsheet. So far so good. But in some cases the autoformat function from Excel changed my values.
For example, I write 'true'/'false' to a cell, but Excel interprets it and translate it.
Second example, I write a telephonenumber to Excel and Excel cuts the leading '0', so '012345' changed to '12345'.

How can I say, that a cell is just a text/string cell?

This is a samplecode, how I write to Excel:

```
ws.get_Range("A1", "A1").Value = "true";
ws.get_Range("A1", "A1").Cells.WrapText = true;
ws.get_Range("A1", "A1").Rows.AutoFit();
```

best regards

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Another way to make Excel treat values as text is to add `'` in front of the values:

```
ws.get_Range("A1").Value = "'0123";
```

The `'` will be visible only in the cell formula but not in it's value/text.

You can also set multiple cells at once:

```
object[,] values = { { "true", "0123" }, { "false", "0125" } };
var range = ws.get_Range("A1:B2")
range.NumberFormat = "@"; // Text format to treat the values as Text
range.Value = values
```

or

```
Clipboard.SetText("'true\t'01234\n'false\t'01235");
ws.get_Range("A1").PasteSpecial(); // or just ws.Paste();
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this for leading zero

```
ws.get_Range("A1", "A1").NumberFormat = "@";
ws.get_Range("A1", "A1").Value = "012345";
```

For boolean value

```
ws.get_Range("B1", "B1").Value = "True/False";
```